# sidebarMenu with subItems is non-responsive in dashboardbody shiny

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I have the below code and upon clicking the "Dataset" in sidebar menu with sub-items, the dashboardbody does not change to the text in the tabItem. Ideally, when "Dataset" is clicked the body should display "Dataset menu sub-items content". I referred similar threads but no success. Could anyone help.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(
menuItem("Documentation", tabName = "documentation"),
menuItem("Dataset", tabName="dataset",icon = icon("info"), 
         menuSubItem(fileInput("Input", "Upload input file:")),

menuSubItem(numericInput("samples",label="Samples",value=0,max=10)))))


body <- dashboardBody(
tabItems(
tabItem(tabName = "documentation",div(p("Dashboard tab content"))),
tabItem(tabName = "dataset",div(p("Dataset menu sub-items content")))))


ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
          sidebar,
          body)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I guess the problem comes that you're not switching to a new tab, you're just expanding it. Without `menuSubItem` code works as expected.

Comment: yes, the issue is with menuSubItem. Is there any way to do this by having menuSubItem?